# Figuring out the equivalent power series based on pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, singularity, frobenius-method

I am trying out to solve a differential equation using a power series solution.

I figured out the recurrence or recursive relation of the constants and I figured out the pattern somehow.

By substituting n values to the recurrence relation, I got a pattern like this.

**Recurrence relation:**
\begin{align}
a_{n}&=\frac{-(-5+2n)a_{n-1}}{(2n+(4(n^{2})))}
 \\ \\
a_{n}&=\frac{(-(-1))(-(-1))(-3)(-3)(-5)(-5)...(-(-5+2n)) a_{0}}{(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)...(2n+4n^{2})}\end{align}

I kind off got how it goes like it has a pattern of odd numbers at the power of 2 and in the denominator is just n! so I got a power series out of it.

$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{((-1)^{n+1})(2n+1)^{2})(a_{0})(x^n)}{(n!)(2n+4n^{2})}$$

To summarize it all, the expression $(2n+1)^{2}$ was to replace the odd numbers at the power of $2$ and the $n!$ to replace the factorial of numbers. And I just left the recurrence or recursive relation. The summation goes to infinity and has an index of $1$ since it had the index of $1$ even before I got the n-values.

Is the power series representation correct?

Comment: You should make use of https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php for the math formatting part. Remember dollar signs to begin and end math with.

Comment: I somehow followed the formatting,please point out any further inconsistencies. Thank you.

Comment: \infty instead of infinity, otherwise it looks good! So $\infty$

Comment: In the recurrence relation, did you mean $$ a_{n}=\frac{-(-5+2n)a_{n-1}}{2n(2n+1)}? $$ The present form is no recurrence. It would help to verify such things if you gave the original differential equation.

Comment: Ah yes. That $a_{0}$ was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the recurrence is 
$$ a_{n}=\frac{-(2n-5)a_{n-1}}{2n(2n+1)}$$
multiply by $$n!(-2)^n(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)$$ (using the recursive relations $-2=(-2)^{n}/(-2)^{n-1}$, $n=n!/(n-1)!$ etc.) to get
\begin{align}
b_n&=(-2)^nn!(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)a_n\\
&=(-2)^{n-1}(n-1)!(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\\
&=b_{n-1}
\end{align}
so that the $b$ sequence is constant with $b_0=3a_0$ and thus
$$
a_n=\frac{3(-2)^{-n}a_0}{n!(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)}.
$$

---

Or in another way, $a_N/a_0$ is the product of all those fractions from $n=1$ to $N$, or the fraction of the products of the single factors,
$$
\frac{a_N}{a_0}=\frac{(-1)^N\prod_{n=1}^N(2n-5)}{2^NN!\prod_{n=1}^N(2n+1)}
$$
Now it takes some observation to remark that most of the odd numbers in the last factors cancel, as $2n+1=2(n+3)-5$. Thus there remains
$$
\frac{a_N}{a_0}=\frac{(-1)^N\prod_{n=1}^3(2n-5)}{2^NN!\prod_{n=N-2}^N(2n+1)}
=\frac{(-1)^N(-3)(-1)(1)}{2^NN!(2N-3)(2N-1)(2N+1)}.
$$

Comment: How did you obtain the expression $n!(−2)n(2n+1)(2n−1)(2n−3)$? and figuring out the recursive relations $-2=\frac{(−2)^{n}}{(−2)^{n−1}}$ and etc.?

Comment: Experience and trying to identify basic recursive relations, like "increasing the index changes the sign", "... removes a factor 2", " .. a factor $n$", "... exchanges a factor $(2n-5)$ by $(2n+1)=(2n-5)+6$". The last then gets complemented by the inner factors, so that the operation is taking away the factor at one end and adding a factor at the other.

Comment: It was kind off hard for me to visualize certain factors that would agree with the recursive relations so what I just did is get values from the n-values and trying to find a pattern on it. Would that kind of solution give the same answer as you have given?

Comment: So in thinking of the factors, we evaluate them per term not as a whole?

Comment: I analyzed your second answer and understood some parts of it and wondered why it the pi notation in the numerator only had up to 3 factors? is it because all of the factors except the 3 factors were cancelled out?

And in the denominator, again in the pi notation is it only by observation that we equate (2n+1)=(2(n+3))-5? what if it had other factors both in the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Also, I noticed that the negative signs where replaced by a (-1)^n term and the $2n$ which in turn was replaced by $2^{N}$ and $N!$ if my observation is correct, would every time a certain number ,for example $a$ is multiplied to n, it is replaced by a $a^{N}$? and the $n$ in turn is replaced by $N!$?

Comment: You have a choice to make how to treat the $2n(2n+1)$ in the denominator. You could combine them to  $(2N+1)!$ but then the factor $(2n-5)$ has no counter part. Or you separate them into 3 components $2^NN!\prod(2n+1)$ where now the odd factor sequences partially cancel.